# Fixing side mirror on my Buick

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a 2005 Buick Lesabre, and I managed to break my side mirror off from its enclosure. In the images, you can see there are 3 sockets on the mirror - 1 large and 2 small. I broke the large one one and you can see the break on the mirror seat.

I brought it in to the auto shop and each one said they would only consider replacing the entire enclosure and quoted a price about 1/10 the worth of the vehicle. Any ideas?

My idea was to use a dremel to grind the whole thing flat and just glue it on. But I'm not sure whether that would make it unadjustable. Any help would be appreciated.

Pictures:

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8877/img20120322141848.jpg

http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/9369/img20120322141859.jpg

Answer (score 4):

If you glue it you most certainly will make it unadjustable.Other options to consider are asking the bodyshop the cost of a nonpower mirror installed but not painted to match.You might also inquire about a junkyard/recycled mirror.I have found that often local auto parts stores can sell or order aftermarket parts as cheap as used parts.You could also try installing it yourself.Generally it only requires removing the inside door panel and the mirror mounting screws.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to save some money and replace the mirror yourself, there is a good how-to video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZSXVx9uyGQ

Answer (score 0):

Hold on!

I have what I believe is the cheap repair solution for Richard Millikan.  Never mind that it's three years too late to matter for him; but it might help somebody else.

You don't have to replace anything but some guts inside the mirror housing.

Not the whole mirror housing;

No concern with matching paint color etc.;

It requires a nearby junk yard, Torx 10 and Torx 15 tools, and some patience.
In my case, if my repair works for me (not finished yet), my outlay will be about $35.00 parts and zero labor, compared to $200-$350 parts and labor costs not estimated...

I will post in a few days.  I want to complete the job, or report what I tried and what didn't work...

Thanks, and Cheers.

Comment: When you do, please just edit this post and update ...